# Excel 2007 - Capture OWC11 Spreadsheet Control's Right-Click Context Menu Selection

Tags: excel, ms-office, vba

I know this is probably simple, but I have spent 2 hours Googling for the answer and I can't find it.  I am using the Office Web Components 2003 (v11) Spreadsheet Control on an Excel 2007 userform.  I am using the BeforeContextMenu event to create a custom context (right-click) menu.  I'm using the code sample from the Spreadsheet Control's help file to create the menu.  The code is:

```
Sub Spreadsheet1_BeforeContextMenu(x, y, Menu, Cancel)

    Dim cmContextMenu(4)
    Dim cmClearSubMenu(2)

    cmClearSubMenu(0) = Array("&All", "ClearAll")
    cmClearSubMenu(1) = Array("&Formats", "ClearFormats")
    cmClearSubMenu(2) = Array("&Values", "ClearValues")

    cmContextMenu(0) = Array("Cu&t", "owc2")
    cmContextMenu(1) = Array("&Copy", "owc3")
    cmContextMenu(2) = Array("&Paste", "owc4")
    cmContextMenu(3) = Empty
    cmContextMenu(4) = Array("Clea&r", cmClearSubMenu)

    Menu.Value = cmContextMenu

End Sub
```

The custom menu appears perfectly when the spreadsheet is right-clicked.  What I can't figure out is how to capture the menu item that I select.  Can someone please point me to VBA code that will enable me to capture and use the selection?

Thanks In Advance -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more Googling I found the answer to this problem in the Help for the OCW11 Spreadsheet Control.  The BeforeContextMenu event lists the code shown in my original post.  I could see that the menu items were defined with statements like:

```
cmContextMenu(0) = Array("Cu&t", "owc2")
```

The "Cu&t" is the menu item label, and the "owc2" is the constant (I assume)  that is supposed to execute the Cut command (commands are known as "OCCommands" in OWC11).  The problem is that the "owc2" constant wasn't firing the Cut command.  I checked the "Programming Information" section of the Help, **underneath "Enumerations,"** in the entry titled "OCCommandID" for the OCCommand ID constants.  That's exactly where they are located.  I looked up the Cut constant, which is 1001, and replaced the "owc2" with 1001, and the Cut command worked perfectly!  I did the same thing for the "&Copy" and "&Paste" commands, with 1002 and 1003, respectively, and they worked as well.

My problem may be that I didn't set up the proper references to the OWC constants.  Or it could be that the constants changed and weren't updated correctly in the Help documentation.  Whichever may be the culprit, the above method fixed the problem.